# Как сделать редирект в htaccess на внешний url без передачи параметра

Tags: .htaccess

Всем привет!

Подскажите как сделать редирект со страницы http://site.ru/cat?id=12 на http://othersite.ru/parampampam при помощи htaccess?
Если делать обычный редирект

```
#redirect /cat?id=12  http://othersite.ru/parampampam
```

то к адресу назначения добавляется cat?id=12 т.е. получается http://othersite.ru/parampampam?id=12 соответственно получаем ошибку :(

Как же все таки перейти на http://othersite.ru/parampampam без ?id=12?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, ставьте статус 301. С ним параметры не передаются.

Comment: пардон, долго эксперементировал с разными вариантами, не правильно в итоге написал, с /cat?id=12 вообще не переходит, видимо параметр мешает, как перейти с /cat?id=12? по redirect

Answer (score 0):

Возможно я забиваю, да еще и неумело, гвозди микроскопом. Но еще один вариант:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cat$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=12$
RewriteRule ^.* http://othersite.ru/parampampam?
```

Comment: К сожалению фокус не удался...
Вот ссылка http://papirus-online.ru/ вот что получается сейчас http://www.office-zakaz.ru/papirus-24?id_category=12

htaccess такой:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Disable Multiviews
Options -Multiviews

# URL rewriting module activation
RewriteEngine on

# URL rewriting rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/category$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_category=12$
RewriteRule ^.* http://office-zakaz.ru/papirus-24?
</IfModule>


# Catch 404 errors
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php